# What is the complete list of functions and objects that I can import with Explicit Imports, using nuxt bridge?

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxt-bridge

I am trying to transition to Nuxt 3, using [nuxt bridge](https://github.com/nuxt/bridge). I am currently on nuxt 2, using the [composition api](https://composition-api.nuxtjs.org/). I see there is this concept of [auto-import](https://nuxt.com/docs/bridge/nuxt3-compatible-api#explicit-imports), but when I look at [the documentation](https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/concepts/auto-imports) I only see that there are two features imported, `ref` and `computed`.

```
import { ref, computed } from '#imports'
```

What else can I reference from `#imports` besides `ref` and `computed`? Is there a complete list of exportable functions or objects for `#imports`? Am I only able to reference `ref` and `computed` from `#imports`?

Comment: I'm not sure but **ref**, **computed** are already available without importing these. Otherwise they are accessible in the **Nuxt Composition API** e.g. `import { ref, computed } from '@nuxtjs/composition-api'`

Comment: **One tip:** It´s easier upgrading to Nuxt 3 by the way ;)